# Python - Replacing every other word in a string? Memorization project

Tags: python

I am working on logic for a memorization project.  I want to be able to receive a sentence from user using **input()** and then replace every letter from every other word with an underscore **"_"**.  For instance, I want to get input:

```
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence:\n\n')
```

Sample input:

**The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.**

I then want python to turn this string into:

**The _____ brown ___ jumped ____ the ____ dog.**

This could get me going in a great direction, a bonus would be an easy way to make is scalable to to only unmask every third word like:

The _____ _____ fox ______ ____ the ____ ___.

or fourth word, or so on.

Here is what I have tried so far that is not working:

```
>>> while i < len(sentence.split()):
...     sentence[i] = "_____"
...     i = i + 2
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

Comment: share what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions that best enable the community to provide helpful assistance.  Also, even if this isn't a homework question, the post [How Do I Ask And Answer Homework Questions (on Stack Overflow)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) might be good reading for you.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach: `while i < len(sentence_.split()): ... sentence_[i] = "_____"`: You try to assign to a character in the original string, not to a word in the list of words.

Generally, you can of course use `str.split` for this, but this will not play well with punctuation, i.e. the `.` after `dog.` would be considered as part of the word.

Instead, you could use a regular expression for finding words (including, e.g., `'` and `-`, but no other punctuation) and then use `re.sub` with a callback function and `itertools.count` to determine the replacement:

```
>>> import re, itertools
>>> c = itertools.count()
>>> text = "The lightning-quick brown fox jump'd over the (lazy) dog."
>>> re.sub(r"[\w'-]+", lambda m: m.group() if next(c) % 2 == 0 else "_"*len(m.group()), text)
"The _______________ brown ___ jump'd ____ the (____) dog."
```

Adapt the `next(c) % 2 == 0` part for other spacings.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the user's input by `inpt`. Say you want to leave every `k`-th word intact. You can do it like this:

```
output = ' '.join([word if n % k == 0 else '_' * len(word) for n, word in enumerate(inpt.split())])
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a for loop that scans for a " " and delete all the characters until the next string.